# Adding dissolve to background image slideshow

Tags: javascript, image, slideshow

Forgive me as I'm more of a CSS/HTML girl. I am working on a background image slideshow:

```
var bgimages=new Array()
bgimages[0]="http://asia.olympus-imaging.com/products/dslr/epl1/sample/images/epl1_sample01.jpg"
bgimages[1]="http://asia.olympus-imaging.com/products/dslr/epl1/sample/images/epl1_sample02.jpg"
bgimages[2]="http://asia.olympus-imaging.com/products/dslr/epl1/sample/images/epl1_sample03.jpg""
bgimages[3]="http://asia.olympus-imaging.com/products/dslr/epl1/sample/images/epl1_sample04.jpg
bgimages[4]="http://asia.olympus-imaging.com/products/dslr/epl1/sample/images/epl1_sample05.jpg"

//preload images
var pathToImg=new Array()
for (i=0;i<bgimages.length;i++)
{
  pathToImg[i]=new Image()
  pathToImg[i].src=bgimages[i]
}

var inc=-1

function bgSlide()
{
  if (inc<bgimages.length-1)
    inc++
  else
    inc=0
  document.body.background=pathToImg[inc].src
}

if (document.all||document.getElementById)
  window.onload=new Function('setInterval("bgSlide()",5000)')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ZXyH/1/
The code does work as is even though it doesn't seem to be displaying in fiddle.

My questions are:

- How do I add a dissolve so it isn't just cutting between images?
- How do I make a background image appear immediately (currently the page stays white for about 5 seconds and then starts the slideshow.

Comment: A fade affect can be achieved by overlaying the next image with an opacity of 0 over the current image. You can then use JQuery.animate to increase the opacity of the next image while decreasing the opacity of the old image.

Comment: The 5 second delay is a result of the web browser loading the image. You can try decreasing the quality of the image, or displaying a loading message while the images are preloaded. (I'm not at my computer at the moment so I can't post a full answer)

Comment: Is there a way to only preload the first two or three so that it takes a shorter time or no? Not sure I follow the fad affect you mentioned. I was wondering if I could just have each image go to and from 0 oppacity rather than adding another layer.